# HTML5 Range / Display Value and Use in Javascript?

Tags: html, slider

I have been wanting to put a range slider for an Application i am working for in University. I want the value that the slider has when the user changes it to be displayed and i also want to use this value to compare it in javacript to some other values with an if statement.

So what i am asking is how can i create a slider and take the current value and use it in Javascript? I hope this makes sense to everyone and sorry for my grammar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below link which is a tutorial to create a slider using HTML5 and CSS.

[Slider Control Creation With HTML5](http://www.developerdrive.com/2012/07/creating-a-slider-control-with-the-html5-range-input/)

Hope this helps.